# Delete an ES container and lost indexes

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, elastic-stack

I have an ELK with 400GB of logs, had to change some settings and delete old ES container, but when I created the new one, lost my previous logs, the logs are still there though at a folder in the host running docker at /elasticsearch/nodes/0

How can I get them back?

(newbie on this stack, I'm going through the docs right now) Thanks!

Comment: Just to clarify, you have deleted your old container, or stopped? Is it still being listed  if you will type `docker ps -a`?

Comment: Create a new container, mount your logs folder to a dir in the container if that is what yo are asking ?

Comment: You might see if it recovers itself given some time.  If you have that much data, and not losing it is important, also consider running a 3-node ES cluster with 2 replicas of each shard (so a single node going down doesn't cause data loss), and routinely backing up the data to somewhere else.

Comment: I deleted the docker so wasn't stopped. Finally found the docker-compose file and after doing some changes (fixing the root cause of ES getting crashed) I was able to get the logs again. I'm planning on making it to k8s, first wanted to get more knowledge on ELK.